# Uniqueness of linear map

Tags: real-analysis

I have read this post: [Definition of differentiability in higher dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3839898/definition-of-differentiability-in-higher-dimensions) and have a few questions regarding the post and the answers.

1. Why does $T$ have to be unique in order for the definition to make sense? The definition requires one linear map and not a unique linear map.
2. Why does it follow that $$\frac{|T_1(h)-T_2(h)|}{||h||} \to 0$$ for $h \to 0$?
3. Why does $T_1(u)=T_2(u)$ follow for all $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$? I unfortunately don't understand the explanation.
   I think a more detailed answer would be really helpful for me. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: In 1), indeed **the definition** is about _a linear transformation $T$_. However, you can show that $T$ is unique. Think about functions $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ it's the same. You need to remember $T$ is derivative of the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

Comment: @Ramanujan Alright, so as far as I understand its not necessary to show that $T$ is unique, but since it is one might as well show it since it is a nice property?

Comment: @user828884 think of it this way -- if we had two linear maps which spit out the "derivative" and they weren't the same thing, what will the derivative of a function be? The first function or the second? We could define both of these functions to be differentiations, but then we have to explore what the derivative is representing in that case.

Comment: @User203940 Yes, that makes sense if I define it as the derivative later on. However only regarding this context, which doesnt define it that way yet, the uniqueness isn't necessary to have the statement is it? The statement only needs existence.

Comment: Yes you are correct, you don't necessarily need uniqueness with this definition. You could call $T$ *a* derivative of $f$ if it satisfies this, then show that there is only one choice so that it is *the* derivative of $f$.

Comment: @User203940 Alright, that makes sense, thank you! I was confused since I didn't see how it was necessary.

Comment: For the proof of uniqueness, suppose there is a point $x$ so that $T_1(x) \neq T_2(x)$. Then we can find a line on which they disagree, the line $\lambda x$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\lambda T_1(x) \neq \lambda T_2(x)$. Now you can take the limit along this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll turn the discussion in the comments into an answer for some officialness.

As I mentioned, we don't necessarily *need* uniqueness apriori. Call $T$ a derivative if it satisfies the definition. Then it might turn out $f$ has many derivatives. This doesn't happen though, so if $T$ satisfies this then $T$ will be *the* derivative.

For the proof of uniqueness, let $T_1$ and $T_2$ satisfy the definition but are such that they are not equal. This means there is some point $x$ so that $T_1(x) \neq T_2(x)$. Now for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $T_1(\lambda x) \neq T_2(\lambda x)$ (why?) so we can take the limit as $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ along this line. This will tell us that the limit is not zero, which is bad. Why is this bad? Well we note that we must have

$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|(T_1 - T_2)(h)\|}{\|h\|} =0,$$
since

$$ \|T_1(h) - T_2(h)\| = \| T_1(h) - f(x+h) + f(x) + f(x+h) - f(x) - T_2(h)\| \leq \|f(x+h) - f(x) - T_1(h)\| + \|f(x+h) - f(x) - T_2(h)\|,$$
and then we plug in the definition.

**Edit:** The last blank to fill in.

Take the curve $\lambda x$. We know along this curve $T_1(\lambda x) \neq T_2(\lambda x)$, so $\lambda(T_1 - T_2)(x) \neq 0$. Examine

$$ \lim_{ \lambda \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|(T_1 - T_2)(\lambda x)\|}{\|\lambda x\|} = \lim_{ \lambda \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|\lambda (T_1 - T_2)(x)\|}{\|\lambda x\|} = \lim_{ \lambda \rightarrow 0} \frac{|\lambda| \|(T_1 - T_2)(x)\|}{|\lambda| \|x\|} = \lim_{ \lambda \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|(T_1 - T_2)(x)\|}{\|x\|}.$$

We know $x \neq 0$ (why?) so $\|x\| \neq 0$, $(T_1 - T_2)(x) \neq 0$ so $\|(T_1 - T_2)(x)\| \neq 0$, and since $\lambda$ doesn't appear in the limit we really have

$$ \lim_{ \lambda \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|(T_1 - T_2)(\lambda x)\|}{\|\lambda x\|} = \frac{\|(T_1-T_2)(x)\|}{\|x\|} \neq 0. $$

Note that I'm implicitly using some things here (namely some norm properties and the fact that the maps are linear).

Comment: If this is not clear I can fill in the details, this is just the gist of Angina's solution (as far as I can tell). I kept it a little vague so you can fill in some details.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, this was really helpful already. So as far as I understand, your last inequality answers my 2nd question, since dividing by $||h||$ and then taking the limit gives me zero. Regarding the 3rd question, we have that $\lambda(T_1(x)-T_2(x)) \neq 0$ for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{0\}$. Why does it now follow that this approaches 0 for $\lambda \to 0$?

Comment: Good question. Recall what a limit means in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It says that if I go along any curve that goes to $0$, I should get the value of the limit. I did things kind of out of order in my post. I showed that the limit of this thing must be zero in the last bit, and then in the second part I showed that if we assume $T_1 \neq T_2$, then I can find a curve (this line $\lambda x$) such that the limit doesn't go to $0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why exactly the limit does not go to $0$? I think this is the last part that is missing for me to understand the proof. Also, I would like to upvote your answers but I unfortunately can't due to the reputation, I am sorry.

Comment: Sure. I'm going to move it to the post.

Comment: @user828884 Let me know if that does the trick. (Also don't worry about upvoting, I care more about you understanding than my reputation.)

Comment: Thank you so much. One last thing though, does it make a difference that you take the limit of a scalar rather than a vector? Before we showed that the limit of the expression regarding a vector valued variable approaches $0$. Why is this equivalent? Intuitively this makes sense, since we have $\lambda x$ as a vector as well, but what would be the formal explanation? Again, thanks so much.

Comment: Yeah that's a good question and what I was trying to say in an earlier comment. When we're saying $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}$ what we really mean is "the limit along all paths going to $0$", where a path is a function $p : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (I think $p$ needs to be at least continuous). This is a tricky thing but I think it should be in most multivariable calc books somewhere.

Comment: This is not rigorous in any way but Paul does at least talk about the idea here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/limits.aspx

Comment: Yes, thats the intuition behind it, which makes sense. I just wondered how one would prove this formally, however if you don't know this right away it doesn't matter that much, you helped me a lot already! Edit: Thank you, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Someone else might be better equipped for that explanation, off of the top of my head I guess the "rigorous" proof is that you have $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $p : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, both continuous so $f \circ p$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and then you can use the limit definition there and it should be equal to $f(p(0)) = f(0)$, and this holds true for all continuous choices of $p$.

Comment: @user828884 It might be a good exercise to show this property using the definitions from Spivak http://strangebeautiful.com/other-texts/spivak-calc-manifolds.pdf